# Помогите грамотно организовать алгоритм заполнения таблицы тасками

Tags: php, mysql, css3, html5, table

Добрый вечер! Нужна помощь советом. Ситуация такая. Имеется таблица на три столбика - TODO, DOING, DONE. Из базы данных достается таск и ложится в ячейку с соответствующим статусом. Тасков может быть неограниченное кол-во. Как сделать равномерное распределение тасков в этой таблице?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ это сделать предобработку массива с тасками, т.е. путём перебора каждого элемента формируешь 3 массива, каждый из которых будет содержать только таски определенного типа. Ну а дальше поочередно добавляешь таски на доску по одному из каждого списка.

Comment: А по html и css что должно получиться? Таблицей или дивами это все делать?

Comment: Ну это уже на ваше усмотрение, смотря какой результат нужен.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы таски с одинаковым статусом ложились в один столбик, друг под другом. Т.е. должно быть три столбика.

Comment: Если столбики будут оформлены как таблица то используйте ее или же дивы стилизируйте под нее.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.